# Creating a function/loop

Tags: r, function, purrr, httr

I have data being pulled from an API, but for the purposes of this, I will use dummy data:

```
test <- structure(list(Id = 201:203, firstname = c("Jackie", "Liz", "Jack"), 
                       lastname = c("Jormpjomp", "Lemon", "Donaghy"), 
                       address = c("4 Main St.", "5 Main St.", "6 Main St."), 
                       zip = c(89044L, 60301L, 85281L), 
                       dob = c(NA, "7/1/88", "2/13/90"), 
                       phone = c("333-333-3333","4444", "555-555-5555"), 
                       statecode = c("NV", "WI", "AZ")), 
                  class = "data.frame", 
                  row.names = c(1, 2, 3))
```

First I isolate all the needed variables as their own values:

```
Ids <- test$Id
firstnames <- test$firstname
lastnames <- test$lastname
addresses <- test$address
zips <- test$zip
dobs <- test$dob
phones <- test$phone
```

Then I create a character vector to add on to the final API call:

```
data_upsert = paste0(
    '{ "Id": ', Ids, ',
  "firstName": "', firstnames, '",
  "lastname": "', lastnames, '",
  "dateOfBirth": "', dobs, '",
  "phones": [ 
               { "phoneNumber": "', phones, '" } ], 
               "addresses": [ 
               { "addressLine1": "', addresses, '", 
               "zipOrPostalCode": "', zips, '",
               } ] } 
  ')
```

Then I make a variable for my header - this will stay the same throughout

```
headers_upsert = c(
  `Accept` = 'application/json',
  `Authorization` = 'Basic JFOJDIFvdhSOFOHAD83820348voqpTOESV==',
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json'
)
```

Finally, I complete the API call, as such:

```
upsert <- httr::POST(url = 'https://api.secure.com/v1/people/Create', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers_upsert), body = data_upsert)
```

Running that creates a response that looks like this:

```
Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/people/Create]
  Date: 2021-08-31 20:28
  Status: 201
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 58 B
{
  "Id": 222323178,
  "status": "UnmatchedStored"
```

I then want to store this response in table form:

```
resContent <- content(res, as="text")

resJSON <- jsonlite::fromJSON(resContent)

resTable <- as.data.frame(resJSON)
```

If you run everything above, it obviously only works with the first row in `test`, but I'm looking for a sleek way to write a function and loop which:

A) Runs the API call for all three rows

B) Creates a table with all three responses

**EDIT: Based on Bing's response:**

After running Bing's response, it accomplishes the first part, but the issue comes in making the table at the end.

The results for `response` looks like this:

```
[[1]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/people/111322450]
  Date: 2021-09-01 15:02
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 1.56 kB
{
  "Id": 111322450,
  "firstName": "Jackie",
  "lastName": "Jormpjomp",
  "middleName": null,
  "suffix": null,
  "title": "Mr.",
  "contactMode": "Person",
  "organizationContactCommonName": null,
  "organizationContactOfficialName": null,
...

[[2]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/people/findOrCreate/]
  Date: 2021-09-01 15:02
  Status: 201
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 58 B
{
  "Id": 111323215,
  "status": "UnmatchedStored"

[[3]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/people/findOrCreate/]
  Date: 2021-09-01 15:02
  Status: 201
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 58 B
{
  "Id": 111323216,
  "status": "UnmatchedStored"
```

When I run:

```
resContent=map(response , httr::content, as="text")

resJSON <- map(resContent, jsonlite::fromJSON)

resTable <- map(resJSON, as.data.frame)
```

`resTable` is still stored as a List that looks like this **EDIT**:

```
$data
$data[[1]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/people/111322450]
  Date: 2021-09-01 18:24
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 1.58 kB
{
  "Id": 111322450,
  "firstName": "Jackie",
  "lastName": "Jormpjomp",
  "middleName": null,
  "suffix": null,
  "title": null,
  "contactMode": "Person",
  "organizationContactCommonName": null,
  "organizationContactOfficialName": null,
...

$data[[2]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/people/findOrCreate/]
  Date: 2021-09-01 18:24
  Status: 201
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 58 B
{
  "Id": 111323215,
  "status": "UnmatchedStored"

$data[[3]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/people/findOrCreate/]
  Date: 2021-09-01 18:24
  Status: 201
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 58 B
{
  "Id": 111323216,
  "status": "UnmatchedStored"


$args
$args[[1]]
[1] "map(jsonlite::fromJSON)"
attr(,"type")
[1] "map"

$args[[2]]
[1] "map(as.data.frame)"
attr(,"type")
[1] "map"


attr(,"class")
[1] "jqr"
```

The only data I need from each response is `Id`

**EDIT #2**

Running the following:

```
resContent=map(response , httr::content)   
    
resTable <- map(resContent, ~.x$Id) %>% as.data.frame()
```

returns the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(.) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"jqr"’ to a data.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

httr::POST is not vectorized. You will need to loop through each one. You can use `lapply` or a tidy version like:

```
library(purrr)
response = map(data_upsert,
  ~httr::POST(url = 'https://www.google.com/', 
           httr::add_headers(.headers=headers_upsert), 
           body = .x))
```

See if these works. **Edits**:

```
resContent=map(response , httr::content)   
    
resTable <- map(resContent, ~.x$Id) #%>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's not giving me the output I'm looking for though. See my edit above.

Comment: ignore that last comment. Noticed I had a package complication in there. Editing now.

Comment: The first part of your answer worked! Thank you. That said, the second part is still giving me issues. Can you take a look at the edit I made?

Comment: @SloppySteaks resTable will be a list. You need to use it to make a table. What does resTable look like?

Comment: Check the new edit I just included! The only data I need from each response is `Id`.

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: What will this give you  map(resContent, ~.x$Id) %>% as.data.frame()

Comment: It returns the following error:

`Error in as.data.frame.default(.) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"jqr"’ to a data.frame`

Comment: remove the "text" part from the resContent=map(response , httr::content) and remove the last part of the next line like this: resTable <- map(resContent, ~.x$Id). What does resContent and resTable look like?

Comment: If I run exactly as you posted in your edit above, I am still met with this error:

`resTable <- map(resContent, ~.x$Id) %>% as.data.frame()
Error in as.data.frame.default(.) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"jqr"’ to a data.frame`

I also made an edit in my original post if that's easier to read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236660/discussion-between-bing-and-sloppysteaks).